# How to open JupyterLab | Jupyter Notebook without browser menus/address bar, as a Desktop App

Tags: google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

How to open JupyterLab | Jupyter Notebook without browser menus/address bar, as a Desktop App?

- As a desktop application (not seeing the browser)
- In any OS (Windows / Linux / Mac), that is, using functionality from the browser, not the OS.
- In Google Chrome, without address bar, and without tabs, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am finding this super useful that is why I want to share it.

If you have JupyterLab installed and running correctly, you normally open it going to something like:

`http://<IP_of_the_machine>:8888/lab`

or

`http://localhost:8888/lab`

if running locally.

If you use it often, you may prefer a more direct way and without the browser.

Something similar to

[image]

First of all, if you have JupyterLab you can also run the simpler Jupyter Notebook just by changing the url

```
# JupyterLab
URL="http://IP:8888/lab"

# Jupyter Notebook
URL="http://IP:8888/tree"
```

And by using the Chrome `--app` option, you could get the 2 windows above with

```
# JupyterLab
URL="http://192.168.1.30:8888/lab"

# Jupyter Notebook
URL="http://192.168.1.30:8888/tree"

# Comment out the one you don't want

/opt/google/chrome/chrome --app="$URL" &
```

(You may have to adapt a bit the script if using Windows)

You can place that in 2 shortcuts on your desktop and with a click you have it up and running.

[image]

This works the same if your Jupyter is remote (On Google Vertex AI for example) as long as the URL doesn't change.

---

Background story: https://superuser.com/questions/1292362/google-chrome-with-minimal-layout-without-address-bar-and-without-tabs